# An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint

Tags: ios, facebook, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a request in `Facebook` with `Corona SDK` with the following code:

```
  local function facebookListener(event)
    if (event.type == "session") then
        if (event.phase == "login") then
            token = event.token
            print("token "..token)

          facebook.request( "me/invitable_friend?access_token="..token)
        elseif (event.type == "request") then
          native.showAlert("Facebook listener", "request")
           if ( not event.isError ) then  
                   native.showAlert("req", event.type)

         --    -- local response = event.response
             print("response "..event.response )
        else 
            native.showAlert("erro", "erro")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The login result returns the token and I make a request....but the request returns the following error in console log:

> FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint 'me/invitable_friend?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED': An open FBSession must be ##

Comment: This one is tough to debug, but I would try and give as much information about the access token you're getting in order to determine what the issue is. Please use developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I used this url to debug ...enter with my access token and everything is ok with it..But in my app I'm getting that an open FBSession must be open...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenate `?` and your parameters, it's better to pass them as a `params` map:

```
local params = {access_token = tostring(token)}
facebook.request("me/invitable_friend","GET", params)
```